# Get row count from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, count

I am trying to get a row count from sqlite for my android application but for some reason its always returning Zero even though I have a enough amount of rows in my DB.

Here is the Code:

```
DatabaseConnector database1 = new DatabaseConnector(getApplicationContext());
int TotalPosts = database1.getIds();


 public int getIds()
       {
           String selectQuery = "SELECT COUNT(Pst_id) AS CountTotal FROM student_posts";           
           SQLiteDatabase database = this.dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
           Cursor c = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);     
           count = c.getColumnIndex("CountTotal");    
           return count;
       }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are assigning a column index to the count variable.

Comment: As @brianestey says, `getColumnIndex` returns the position of the column in the returned data set and NOT the value of what is in that column. In your case as you are only querying for a single value, i.e., `COUNT` you will only get one column and it's index will always be 0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like below:

```
public int getIds()
    {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT Pst_id FROM student_posts";           
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int total = c.getCount();
    c.close();

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :) just waiting for 6 more minutes to accept this answer :(

Comment: Don't forget to close the cursor before returning!

Answer (score 4):

Try `c.getCount()`..

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29)

Hope this helps..